# What is the Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, normal-distribution, fourier-transform

I remember there is a special rule for this kind of function, but I can't remember what it was.

Does anyone know?

Comment: The way it is usually normalized, the transform of $e^{-x^2/2}$ is itself. If you drop the half as you wrote, you get $e^{-x^2/4} / \sqrt {2}$

Comment: my textbook says we first have to calculate the derivative and solve it by making the derivative = -w/2f(w) , are you familiar with that method ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Caveat: I'm using the normalization $\hat f(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-it\omega}\,dt$.

A cute way to to derive the Fourier transform of $f(t) = e^{-t^2}$ is the following trick: Since $$f'(t) = -2te^{-t^2} = -2tf(t),$$
taking the Fourier transfom of both sides will give us
$$i\omega \hat f(\omega) = -2i\hat f'(\omega).$$

Solving this differential equation for $\hat f$ yields
$$\hat f(\omega) = Ce^{-\omega^2/4}$$
and plugging in $\omega = 0$ finally gives
$$ C = \hat f(0) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt = \sqrt{\pi}.$$

I.e. $$ \hat f(\omega) = \sqrt{\pi}e^{-\omega^2/4}.$$

Comment: Thanks yes that seems familiar                                                   could you explain how you get to the step ................                         taking the Fourier transfom of both sides will give us
$$i\omega \hat f(\omega) = -2i\hat f'(\omega).$$

Comment: Those should be familiar "rules" for Fourier transforms: The Fourier transform of $f'(t)$ is $i\omega \hat f(\omega)$ and the FT of $tf(t)$ is $-i\hat f'(\omega)$. If they are not familiar, they follow fairly easily from the definition of the Fourier transform.

Comment: Furthermore why does e^-infinity - e^ infinity = square root(pi) ?

Comment: the Fourier transform of t , you mean integral limits +infitniy,-infinity te^-iwt

Comment: @SF your last two comments make no sense.

Comment: my question was after plugging in w=0 , why does the answer = root pi ?

Comment: That is a *very* well known integral. See for example http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html

Comment: I have no come across Gaussian integral before, perhaps I am able to assume it, and not expected to work it out
..............
could you explain how the Fourier transform of f′(t) is iωf^(ω)

Comment: If you can't find it in your textbook (which you should be able to), try partial integration.

Comment: @mrf when FT the right side of the first equation,  $-2 tf(t)$, using that FT of $tf(t)$ is $-iF'(ω)$ shouldn't that yield  $+2 iF'(ω)$? I just don't get it where the minus in $−2 i F′(ω)$ comes from. Thanks.

Comment: @mrf I think I found it. According to your definition $$\hat f(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-it\omega}\,dt.$$ Differentiation yields $$i\frac{d}{d\omega}\hat f(\omega) = i
\int f(t)  \frac{d}{d\omega} e^{-it\omega}\,dt =  \int tf(t) e^{-it\omega}\,dt$$ In other words, the FT of $tf(t)$ is +$i\hat f'(\omega)$. There is no minus in this relationship when using your definition of FT. So your brilliant answer is correct just the comment below contains a superflous minus when stating that relationship in my opinion.

Comment: Why actually plugging in $0$  for $\omega$ in order to determine  $C$ ? Why that initial condition?

Comment: @Leon You have $\hat f(\omega) = Ce^{-\omega^2/4}$ for some value of $C$. You can determine the constant from any value of $\hat f(\omega)$, but it seems like $\omega = 0$ gives the simplest computations, doesn't it?