# why is fourier transform of AWGN is of the form complex

Tags: normal-distribution, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

This is related to this Nice answer by the thread

[What is the Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381597/what-is-the-fourier-transform-of-fx-e-x2).

Considering this derivation of fourier transform of Gaussian with mean 0 and unit variance, why do we get complex data type when I take fourier transform of AWGN (Addititive white gaussian noise) ?. (You can try in matlab by taking FFT of awgn function.)

"""

no_sig = zeros(128,256);

no_sig_noise = awgn(no_sig,0);

no_sig_fft = fft2(no_sig_noise);

"""

if you observe no_sig_fft, it has complex form (a+jb).
My question is : As per the derivation, the Fourier transform of Gaussian distributed data is :
$e^{-w^2/4}$ , which will give real data. But when i do fft of AWGN, i get complex data ($a+jb$).
Why is this so. Anything i have missed in understanding?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please see if this clarifies my question.