# How to solve the Fourier transformation of a function of the form $e^{-(x-a)^2}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I have no idea how to continue to find a solution for an Fourier transformation of the form $\exp\left\{-(x-a)^2\right\}$, this is what I tried (already found):

$$\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\left\{-(x-a)^2\right\}\exp\{-2\pi \textbf{i}\:\omega x\} \,dx$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\left\{-(x-a)^2 -2\pi \textbf{i}\:\omega x\right\} \,dx $$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\{-x^2 +2ax -a^2 -2\pi \textbf{i}\:\omega x\} \,dx $$
$$= e^{-a^2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\left\{-x^2 -x(2a-2\pi \textbf{i} \:\omega)\right\} \,dx $$

But here I have no idea what to do

Comment: Anyone know what the command is for Fourier transform symbol I tried \mathcal{F} but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: you can use detexify to draw the symbol and see closest latex symbols

Answer (score 1):

With substitution $y=x-a$, you can "translate" it so that this helps:
[What is the Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381597/what-is-the-fourier-transform-of-fx-e-x2)

Comment: I'll try thank you