# What is the fourier transform of $e^{-\frac{t^2}2}$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, exponential-function, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

What is the fourier transform of $e^{-\frac{t^2}2}$. I need a classical solution, I mean, straight-forward. done by hand, without using tricks and convolutions. Many thanks in advance

First steps, am I on the right way?

[image: First steps, am I on the right way?]

Comment: You'll probably not get much help, and even down voted (as I see 2 people already have !) or closed unless you show your own working first. What have you tried yourself? (show this in your question). Some related hints: what is the definition of the Fourier transform in terms of an integral? Can you evaluate that integral by hand? Or do you need a table of Fourier transforms? Etc... For example, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition

Comment: @Antinous okay I will add my resolution steps in 20 minutes (cause i can't take a picture right now) if you need some proof of my effort (I wouldn't ask if I hadn't tried before though ._.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270566/how-to-calculate-the-fourier-transform-of-a-gaussian-function)

Comment: @Hans Lundmark it is not, bc I have asked about classic resolution, without convolutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution involves completing the square in the exponent of the integrand, and then performing a $u$ substitution to get a well known integral that evaluates to 1:

$$\begin{align*}\mathscr{F}\left\{e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\right\}&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}e^{-2\pi i s t} dt\\
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t^2+4\pi i st)} dt\\
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t^2+4\pi i st-4\pi^2s^2)} e^{-2\pi^2s^2}dt\\
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t+2\pi i s)^2} e^{-2\pi^2s^2}dt\\
\\
&=  e^{-2\pi^2s^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\pi}}+2\sqrt{\pi} i s\right)^2}dt\\
\\
&=  e^{-2\pi^2s^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\sqrt{2\pi} i s\right)^2}dt\\
\\
&=  {\sqrt{2\pi}}{e^{-2\pi^2s^2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi u^2}du\\
\\\
&=  {\sqrt{2\pi}}{e^{-2\pi^2s^2}}\\
\\
&= {\sqrt{2\pi}} {e^{-\pi\left(\sqrt{2\pi}s\right)^2}}\\
\\
&= \mathscr{F}\left\{e^{-\pi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^2}\right\}
\end{align*}$$