# Gaussian-like integral : $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos( a x) \ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: analysis, integration

Prove that :

$$ \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-\frac{a^2}{4} } =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos( a x) \ \mathrm{d}x$$

---

the only thing I can think of is differentiating the RHS and trying to get :

$$ -2 f'(a) =a f(a) $$
But I couldn't do it. 
Can anyone show me how to do this ?

Comment: Mh did you try it with $$\cos(ax)=\frac{1}{2} (e^{iax}+e^{-iax})$$

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Differential Equation Approach**

Note that since the integrand is even we have
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1
$$
Then differentiating with respect to $a$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}x\sin(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin(ax)\,\mathrm{d}e^{-x^2}\tag{2b}\\
&=-\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}\sin(ax)\tag{2c}\\
&=-\frac a2\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2d}\\
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(2a)}$: differentiate
$\text{(2b)}$: prepare to integrate by parts
$\text{(2c)}$: integrate by parts
$\text{(2d)}$: $\mathrm{d}\sin(ax)=a\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Since $f'(a)=-\frac a2f(a)$ has the solution $f(a)=ce^{-a^2/4}$ and $f(0)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$,
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\,e^{-a^2/4}\tag3
$$

---

**Contour Integral Approach**

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4a}\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}e^{iax}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4b}\\
&=\frac12e^{-a^2/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left(x-ia/2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4c}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\,e^{-a^2/4}\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
$\text{(4a)}$: symmetry
$\text{(4b)}$: $\sin(ax)$ is odd in $x$
$\text{(4c)}$: complete the square
$\text{(4d)}$: [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\sqrt\pi$

Comment: How do you get the third equality when you differentiate wrt a? When you go from $d\exp(-x^2)$ to $d\sin(ax)$?

Comment: @user103341: the differentiation with respect to $a$ is in the first equality. The extra $x$ is then used in the second equality as $-e^{-x^2}x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12\mathrm{d}e^{-x^2}$. The third equality is integration by parts.

Comment: @robjohn May I ask what is the reasoning for the last equation (the equation after "Thus,")? I follow your argument till that line. I have yet to take a course in complex analysis. Thanks!

Comment: @GalvinNg: the solution to the differential equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}f(a)=-\frac a2f(a)$ is $c\,e^{-a^2/4}$ (divide both sides by $f(a)$ and integrate). Then we just use the well known $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$ to compute $c$.

Comment: @robjohn Why can we take the derivative inside the improper integral as opposed to a bounded interval?

Comment: @Dude111: because the convergence is absolute and uniform over the range of $a$ in which we are interested.

Comment: Dear @robjohn can you please explain more how you substituted $cos(ax)$ by $exp(iax)$? (I do know the complex form of the cosine function)

Comment: $e^{iax}=\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax)$ and since $\sin(ax)$ is odd, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\sin(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @robjohn Equation (4c) has a misprint, it is supposed to be `dx` and not `dt`.

Comment: @TeXApprentice: Indeed, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of cosine, take $e^{iax}$ and complete the square. This thing says that the Fourier transform of the standard normal distribution is itself.

Comment: Nice observation (if the reader knows Fourier Analysis) (+1)

Comment: @robjohn, thanks. It may not be helpful. On the other hand, it shows why this particular integral is important. So, a worthwhile add-on when there are also answers that are easier to follow.

Comment: No question there. $e^{-\pi x^2}$ is an important function for showing sharp estimates, etc. since it is its own Fourier Transform (variations for other normalizations of the Fourier Transform). Not too long ago, I used this in an answer regarding the [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/253928).

Answer (score 11):

Notice that
$$
  a f(a) + 2 f^\prime(a) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2) \left( a \cos(a x) - 2 x \sin(a x) \right) \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^\infty \frac{ \mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \sin\left(a x\right) \right) \mathrm{d} x = 0
$$
It now only remains to find $f(0) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-x^2) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} $.

Answer (score 11):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\cos\pars{ax}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\cos\pars{ax}\,\dd x}
> =\half\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\expo{\ic\verts{a}x}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&=\half\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \expo{-\pars{x -\ic\verts{a}/2}^{2} - a^{2}/4}\,\dd x
> =\half\,\expo{-a^{2}/4}
> \Re\int_{-\infty - \verts{a}\,\ic/2}^{\infty - \verts{a}\,\ic/2}
> \expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x
> \\[5mm]&=\half\,\expo{-a^{2}/4}\
> \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x}_{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{\root{\pi}}}}\ =\
> \color{#66f}{\large{\root{\pi} \over 2}\,\expo{-a^{2}/4}}
> \end{align}

Comment: What does $\Re$ mean in your proof?

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso It denotes the real part of a complex number.

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to integrate $e^{-z^2}$ around a rectangle in the complex plane with vertices at $R,R+ia,-R+ia$ and $-R$.

Another approach is to expand $\cos ax$ in a Maclaurin series and then switch the order of integration and summation. You'll end up with a constant times the Maclaurin series of $e^{\frac{-a^{2}}{4}}$.

Answer (score 4):

A nice simple, but useful, modification of this is that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\cos(ax)dx = \exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2 a^2}{2}\right)
$$
which helps for developing the Fourier series of the Gaussian.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate
$$f(z)=e^{-z^2},z\in\mathbb{C}$$
On the boundary of the rectangle
$$\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re(z)\in[-R,R]\wedge \Im(z)\in[0,a/2]\}$$
Given $a>0,R>a/2.$

Being $f$ entire, this integral is equal to zero.
Using the fact that
$$\int_0^\infty{e^{-x^2}dx}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$$
And observing that on the two vertical sides the integral approaches zero as $R \to \infty$, you will deduce that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)dx}=\sqrt{\pi}\cdot e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}},$$
And also
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{e^{-x^2}\sin(ax)dx}=0.$$
Therefore, by the fact that the function is even, we have that
$$\int_{0}^\infty{e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)dx}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}.$$