# Need help to solve a definit integral using Fourier transform.

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

Hi I have some problem with solving the following definit integral.
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\big(\dfrac{t}{\tau}\big)^2-\dfrac{i\omega t}{2}}\textrm{d}t
$$
My guess to solve it is by using Fourier transform. I need somehow get write it on the form
$$
F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}
$$
And after i get it on this form I can simply look up in a table what $F(\omega)$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Alternatively, one may observe that, by parity of the integrand, your integral reduces to
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\Big(\dfrac{t}{\tau}\Big)^2-\dfrac{i\omega t}{2}}\textrm{d}t=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\Big(\dfrac{t}{\tau}\Big)^2}\cos \Big(\dfrac{\omega t}{2} \Big)\:\textrm{d}t
$$ then one may use the [standard result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317249/gaussian-like-integral-int-0-infty-e-x2-cos-a-x-mathrmdx):
$$
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos( a x) \ \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-\large\frac{a^2}{4}}.
$$

Comment: May I ask why you didn't include $-i\sin (\dfrac{\omega t}{2})$. Was it because it's an odd function over a even intervall os the integral win sinus will be zero?