# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\cos(xu)du$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do I evaluate $$\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\cos(xu)du$$

Any hints?

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-u%5E2)*cos(xu)+du+from+0+to+infinity) this is equal to $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}$.

Comment: It is even so look at $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2} \cos(xu)du$. Note that for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ : $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2-2au}du=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(u+a)^2+a^2}du=e^{a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}du = e^{a^2} \sqrt{\pi}  $. Then extend to $a \in \mathbb{C}$ by analytic continuation, and conclude with $a = ix$

Comment: Let $I(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \cos(xu) du$ ... calculate $\frac{dI}{dx}$ ... also integrate the original integral by part (integrate 1) ... I am still working out the detail :-)

Comment: @BenS. Can you show the OP how to derive this?

Comment: You might like to consider $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-(u-\tfrac{ix}{2})^2\right)\,du$ and some multiple of its real part

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317249/321264

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may differentiate under the integral sign: let $J(x) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-u^2}\cos{xu} \, du$. We have
$$ J'(x) = -\int_0^{\infty} ue^{-u^2}\sin{xu} \, du $$
Integrating by parts,
$$ J'(x) = \left[\frac{1}{2} e^{-u^2}\sin{xu} \right]_0^{\infty} - \frac{x}{2}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-u^2}\cos{xu} \, du, $$
so $J'(x) = -\frac{x}{2}J(x)$. We also know $J(0) = \sqrt{\pi}/2$, and solving the differential equation gives
$$ J(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-x^2/4}. $$

Answer (score 4):

We have 
$$\int_0^\infty\!du\,e^{-u^2} \cos(xu) = \frac12 \mathop{\rm Re}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!du\,e^{-u^2} e^{ixu}$$
shifting the contour to $ u= v+ i x/2$ with $v\in\mathbb{R}$ and noting that the contributions at $|u| \to \infty$ vanish, we obtain
$$\int_0^\infty\!du\,e^{-u^2} \cos(xu)= \frac12 \mathop{\rm Re}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\!dv\, e^{-v^2 -x^2/4} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2 e^{-x^2/4}. $$

Comment: You should warn first the OP that this solution assumes knowledge of contour integration. It is likely that he/she hasn't had lectures on this subject.