# Integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \cos\alpha x \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Value of  $\int_0^\infty  e^{-x^2}  \cos\alpha x     \ dx$

(i) $\frac {\sqrt \pi}{2}e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}}$

(ii)$\frac { \pi}{2}e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}}$

(iii) $\frac {\sqrt \pi}{2}$

(iv) $e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{4}}$

Explain the answer.

Comment: Realistically the best idea is to note that the above is $\textrm{Re} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} e^{i \alpha x} dx$, then complete the square.

Comment: I hoped this was a question about the applications for the gamma function...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317249/321264

Answer (score 3):

Let us write $$I(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \cos(ax)dx$$. It is known that $I(0) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$. Taking a derivative wrt $a$ and per partes we get
$$I'(a) = -\frac{a}{2}I(a)$$
Solution of this differential equation is $$I(a) = A e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}$$
Substituting the known value at zero for our integral we get desired result.

Comment: Note : This method I found in Nahin's Inside interesting integrals p. 77