# How to prove these two integral equalities?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $y'+xy=1$, the solution is:

$$y=Ce^{-x^2/2}+e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^xe^{t^2/2}dt$$
With Laplace trasform, another solution is found as:

$$y=C\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\cos(xt)dt+\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\sin(xt)dt$$
Since the ODE has a unique solution, these two solutions must be identical. How to prove these two integral equalities?

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\cos(xt)dt=\sqrt\frac{\pi}2e^{-x^2/2} \\
&\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\sin(xt)dt=e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^xe^{t^2/2}dt
\end{align}
I got a proof with the Taylor series of $\cos(xt)$ and $\sin(xt)$. Is there any other proof without using the Taylor series?

Comment: Did you try piecewise integration ?

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317249/gaussian-like-integral-int-0-infty-e-x2-cos-a-x-mathrmdx)

Comment: WA gives us the following solution $$y(x)=c_1 e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the guys who comment for the solution hints. I have derived a proof with Gaussian integral erf(x) and erfi(x) functions.

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\cos(xt)dt+i\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\sin(xt)dt\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}e^{ixt}dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2+ixt}dt\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}e^{-(t^2-2ixt-x^2)/2}dt=e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(t-ix)^2/2}dt\\
&=e^{-x^2/2}\left [\sqrt\frac{\pi}2\operatorname{erf}\left ( \frac{t-ix}{\sqrt2} \right )  \right ]_{t=0}^{t=\infty}\\
&=\sqrt\frac{\pi}2e^{-x^2/2}\left [\operatorname{erf}\left ( \frac{\infty-ix}{\sqrt2}\right )-\operatorname{erf}\left ( \frac{-ix}{\sqrt2}\right )\right]\\
&=\sqrt\frac{\pi}2e^{-x^2/2}\left [1+i\operatorname{erfi}\left ( \frac x{\sqrt2}\right )\right]\\
&=\sqrt\frac{\pi}2e^{-x^2/2}+ie^{-x^2/2}\int_0^xe^{t^2/2}dt\\ \\
&Note: \operatorname{erf}(\infty)=1,\quad\operatorname{erf}(-x)=-\operatorname{erf}(x),\quad\operatorname{erf}(ix)=i\operatorname{erfi}(x)
\end{align}
So these two equalities are proved.
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\cos(xt)dt=\sqrt\frac{\pi}2e^{-x^2/2} \\
&\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\sin(xt)dt=e^{-x^2/2}\int_0^xe^{t^2/2}dt
\end{align}