# Shifted Gaussian-like integral: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(x-\mu)^2} \cos(b x) dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, gaussian-integral

I need to compute a definite integral of the form:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a(x-\mu)^2} \cos(b x) dx \qquad \text{with } a > 0.
$$

I understand that for $\mu = 0$, this integral has a well-known solution (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317249/gaussian-like-integral-int-0-infty-e-x2-cos-a-x-mathrmdx)). However, any chance that the expression above has a closed-form solution too?

Comment: Hint: Considering $e^{i b x}$ instead of $\cos(bx)$ makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $y=x-\mu$ and use the  identity $\cos (by+b\mu)=\cos (by) \cos (b\mu)-\sin (by) \sin (b\mu)$.

Note: $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \sin ( a x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ can also be evaluated by the method in the link you gave.

Comment: Thanks, that was much easier than I initially thought... (also the $\sin$ part disappears in my case because of symmetry).