# complex integral involving gaussian and $\sin(sx)$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was trying to compete the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x\exp\left(-\,{x^{2} \over 2}\right)\sin\left(sx\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$

Comment: Hi! Please provide [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/695196) for your question: What have you tried? Where does the problem come from? Otherwise, your question will be likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: This question came from attempting fourier inverse to PDE equation, I have tried to write things in term of complex variable but it is not going anywhere

Comment: @rasheda564 please put the context in your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We know that [$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos(ax)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317249/695196). Recalling [Feynman's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we get
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\sin(sx)\,\mathrm{d}x &=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\int_0^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\cos(sx)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
& \overset{x \to \sqrt{2}x}{=}-\sqrt{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(\sqrt{2}sx)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
& = -\sqrt{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}\right)\\
& =\boxed{ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} se^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}}
\end{align}