# Heisenberg uncertainty principle in D-dimensional

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics

For Heisenberg uncertainty principle in D-dimensional there is $d^2$ in the formula.where does this additional term comes compared with the case of one dimensional?

Comment: Not everyone uses the same notation, such as "$d$". Can you state the relevant formula involving $d$?

Comment: This question might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/253844/131822