# Uncertainty principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Long time ago, I read in a math textbook a statement about functions of complex variables. It was a named uncertainty principle. The name attached was NOT Heisenberg. I know of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. The one I read in that textbook was similar but seemed more fundamental. **Are there any uncertainty principles in the theory of complex variables?**

Comment: Cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Harmonic_analysis)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I was Hardy's uncertainty principle! (I remember now: the book was Hörmander's) Thank you.

Comment: [Heisenberg uncertainty principle in $d$ dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253844/heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-in-d-dimensions) says that $$\frac{\|xf(x)\|_2}{\|f(x)\|_2}\frac{\|\xi\hat{f}(\xi)\|_2}{\|\hat{f}(x)\|_2}\ge\frac{d}{4\pi}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is [Hardy's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Hardy%27s_uncertainty_principle) in harmonic analysis.

Comment: It's not easy to find Hardy's uncertainty principle in that page/via that top-level link. Terry Tao has [a blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/hardys-uncertainty-principle/) mentioning Hardy's Uncertainty 
Principle and a weak form of it.